# AngularJS Jasmine test functions defined on a new scope

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a function within my controller, where I create a new scope and define functions on that scope.

```
function exampleController($rootScope) {
    let vm = this;
    vm.openDialog = openDialog;

    function openDialog() {
        let scope = $rootScope.$new(true);
        scope.exampleFunction = () => {
            scope.value1 = 123;
            //doMoreThings
        };
        ngDialog.open({
            template: 'template/path',
            scope
        });
    }
```

This is a very basic example, just to illustrate the kind of situation I'm talking about.

Is there any way I can test the functions defined on the scope? I tried defining the function on the controller and setting the scope function like so:

```
scope.exampleFunction = exampleFunction;
```

I'm guessing this is the path I need to take, but as the function needs access to the scope itself this wasn't too successful. This issue is I don't know how to pass the scope as a parameter within the html.

I only ask as the functions I'm using have gotten quite large and significantly reduce the code coverage when they are untested.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What test result did you get when u tried to call `scope.exampleFunction()` in your spec file ?

Comment: scope is a local variable to the function so is not accessible within the spec file I believe

Comment: Just figured out a solution which I will post. I was correct that you can't directly access scope variable within specs, but there is a workaround so that you can

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround so you can access the scope variable within the test spec.
Essentially you spy on the creation of the new scope and return your own object that you can access. Like so:

```
describe('openDialog', () => {
    it('should carry out exampleFunction', () => {
        let scope = {};
        spyOn($rootScope, '$new').and.returnValue(scope);
        controller.openDialog();
        scope.exampleFunction();
        //expect some condition resulting from exampleFunction
    });
});
```